# Place figure next to two enumerate environments, side by side

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, enumerate, sidebyside

This is what I'd like to have:
[image]

This is what I've currently got:

```latex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{import}
\pdfminorversion=7
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{transparent}
\newcommand{\incfig}[2][]{%
  \def\svgwidth{#1\columnwidth}
  \import{./figures/}{#2.pdf_tex}
}

\begin{document}
Copy each of the following expressions onto your paper and either state the
value or state that the value is undefined or doesn't exist. Make sure that
when discussing the values you use proper terminology. All expressions are in
reference to the function $g$ shown in Figure~\ref{fig:limit_graph}.

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.4\linewidth}
  \centering
  \caption{$y = g(x)$}
  \incfig[0.4]{limit-graph}
  \label{fig:limit_graph}
\end{wrapfigure}
$ $
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item[\textbf{2.)}] $g(5)$.
      \vspace{2cm}
    \item[\textbf{10.)}] $g(-2)$.
      \vspace{2cm}
    \item[\textbf{12.)}] $\lim_{x \to 2^{+}} g(t)$.
      \vspace{2cm}
    \end{enumerate}\columnbreak\begin{enumerate}
    \item[\textbf{3.)}] $\lim_{t \to 5} g(t)$.
      \vspace{2cm}
    \item[\textbf{11.)}] $\lim_{t \to 2^{-}} g(t)$.
      \vspace{2cm}
    \item[\textbf{13.)}] $\lim_{x \to -2} g(t)$.
      \vspace{2cm}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

Create tables similar to Tables 2.1.3 and 2.1.4 from which you can deduce
each of the following limit values. Make sure that you include table numbers,
table captions, and meaningful column headings. Make sure that your input
values follow patterns similar to those used in Tables 2.1.3 and 2.1.3. Make
sure that you round your output values in such a way that a clear and
compelling pattern in the output is clearly demonstrated by your stated
values. Make sure that you state the limit value!
[\textbf{\textit{2pts}}] \\\\

\textbf{19.)} $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 1^{+}} \frac{\sin(x + 1)}{3x + 3}$.
\end{document}
```

But this is the output:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the problem? BTW, Please make your MWE compilable. We haven't your image file.

Comment: Instead of using a `wrapfigure`, couldn't you make the `multicol` environment have three columns and place the diagram into the third?

Comment: @JasperHabicht I tried using `multicol` before, and it screws everything up with the formatting. Maybe that's just the way I did it, IDK. @pascal974 gave me the solution.

Comment: Totally off topic, but your legend is `$y=g(x)$` and your axis is labelled `$t$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```latex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{import}
\pdfminorversion=7
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{transparent}
\newcommand{\incfig}[2][]{%
  \def\svgwidth{#1\columnwidth}
  \import{./figures/}{#2.pdf_tex}
}

\begin{document}
Copy each of the following expressions onto your paper and either state the
value or state that the value is undefined or doesn't exist. Make sure that
when discussing the values you use proper terminology. All expressions are in
reference to the function $g$ shown in Figure~\ref{fig:limit_graph}.

\begin{wrapfigure}[7]{r}{0.4\linewidth}
  \centering
  \incfig[0.4]{limit-graph}
  \caption{$y = g(x)$}
  \label{fig:limit_graph}
\end{wrapfigure}
$ $
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item[\textbf{2.)}] $g(5)$.
      \vspace{2cm}
    \item[\textbf{10.)}] $g(-2)$.
      \vspace{2cm}
    \item[\textbf{12.)}] $\lim_{x \to 2^{+}} g(t)$.
      \vspace{2cm}
    \end{enumerate}\columnbreak\begin{enumerate}
    \item[\textbf{3.)}] $\lim_{t \to 5} g(t)$.
      \vspace{2cm}
    \item[\textbf{11.)}] $\lim_{t \to 2^{-}} g(t)$.
      \vspace{2cm}
    \item[\textbf{13.)}] $\lim_{x \to -2} g(t)$.
      \vspace{2cm}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\vspace{1.1cm}

Create tables similar to Tables 2.1.3 and 2.1.4 from which you can deduce
each of the following limit values. Make sure that you include table numbers,
table captions, and meaningful column headings. Make sure that your input
values follow patterns similar to those used in Tables 2.1.3 and 2.1.3. Make
sure that you round your output values in such a way that a clear and
compelling pattern in the output is clearly demonstrated by your stated
values. Make sure that you state the limit value!
[\textbf{\textit{2pts}}] \\\\

\textbf{19.)} $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 1^{+}} \frac{\sin(x + 1)}{3x + 3}$.
\end{document}
```

Here's the output:

[image]

I didn't change much. I just changed the location of the caption and explicitly gave the number of lines to wrap around to `wrapfigure` so it doesn't continue to wrap around the next paragraph.

Comment: Only difference between your "answer" and question is position of figure caption ...

Comment: You should point out which adjustments exactly you made: for example, explicitly giving a number of lines to the `wrapfigure` environment, so that it does not affect the following paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

I propose to use the tasks package and put the graph in a minipage

```
    %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661529/place-figure-next-to-two-enumerate-enivronments-side-by-side
    \documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{tasks}
    \usepackage{graphicx}


    \parindent=0pt
    \settasks{label=\bfseries\arabic*.),label-width=2em}
    \begin{document}
    Copy each of the following expressions onto your paper and either state the
    value or state that the value is undefined or doesn't exist. Make sure that
    when discussing the values you use proper terminology. All expressions are in
    reference to the function $g$ shown in Figure.

    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\linewidth}
        \vspace{0pt}
    \begin{tasks}[start=2](2)
        \task $g(5)$.
        \vspace{2cm}
        \task $g(-2)$.
        \vspace{2cm}
    \end{tasks}
    \begin{tasks}[start=10](2)
        \task $\lim_{x \to 2^{+}} g(t)$.
        \vspace{2cm}
        \task $\lim_{t \to 5} g(t)$.
        \vspace{2cm}
        \task $\lim_{t \to 2^{-}} g(t)$.
        \vspace{2cm}
        \task $\lim_{x \to -2} g(t)$.
        \vspace{2cm}
    \end{tasks}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
        \vspace{0pt}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
        $y = g(x)$
    \end{minipage}

    Create tables similar to Tables 2.1.3 and 2.1.4 from which you can deduce
    each of the following limit values. Make sure that you include table numbers,
    table captions, and meaningful column headings. Make sure that your input
    values follow patterns similar to those used in Tables 2.1.3 and 2.1.3. Make
    sure that you round your output values in such a way that a clear and
    compelling pattern in the output is clearly demonstrated by your stated
    values. Make sure that you state the limit value!
    [\textbf{\textit{2pts}}] 

    \begin{tasks}[start=19](2)
    \task $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 1^{+}} \frac{\sin(x + 1)}{3x + 3}$.
    \end{tasks}
    \end{document}
```

**EDIT2** problem space
A better solution with paracol.

The debug option of the package is very interesting

```
            %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661529/place-figure-next-to-two-enumerate-enivronments-side-by-side
            \documentclass{report}
            \usepackage{graphicx}
            \usepackage{tasks}
            \usepackage{paracol}

            \parindent=0pt
            \settasks{label=\bfseries\arabic*.),label-width=2em,before-skip = 0pt,after-skip=2cm,after-item-skip = 2cm,debug}
            %\settasks{label=\bfseries\arabic*.),label-width=2em,before-skip = 0pt,after-skip=2cm,after-item-skip = 2cm}
            \begin{document}

            Copy each of the following expressions onto your paper and either state the
            value or state that the value is undefined or doesn't exist. Make sure that
            when discussing the values you use proper terminology. All expressions are in
            reference to the function $g$ shown in Figure~\ref{fig:limit_graph}.

            \smallskip
            \begin{paracol}{2}
        \begin{tasks}[start=2](2)
        \task $g(5)$.
        \task $g(-2)$.
    \end{tasks}
    \begin{tasks}[start=10](2)
        \task $\lim_{x \to 2^{+}} g(t)$.
        \task $\lim_{t \to 5} g(t)$.
        \task $\lim_{t \to 2^{-}} g(t)$.
        \task $\lim_{x \to -2} g(t)$.
    \end{tasks}
    \switchcolumn
    \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=7cm]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{$y = g(x)$}
    \label{fig:limit_graph}    
    \end{figure}
    \end{paracol}       

            Create tables similar to Tables 2.1.3 and 2.1.4 from which you can deduce
            each of the following limit values. Make sure that you include table numbers,
            table captions, and meaningful column headings. Make sure that your input
            values follow patterns similar to those used in Tables 2.1.3 and 2.1.3. Make
            sure that you round your output values in such a way that a clear and
            compelling pattern in the output is clearly demonstrated by your stated
            values. Make sure that you state the limit value!
            [\textbf{\textit{2pts}}] 

            \begin{tasks}[start=19]
            \task $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 1^{+}} \frac{\sin(x + 1)}{3x + 3}$.
            \end{tasks}
            \end{document}
```